# Changing variable in a second derivative

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I want to convert the differentiation variable in a second derivative, but it's a bit more complicated than the case of the first derivative. For context, the variable $\eta$ is a dimensionless density and $V$ a volume. I have the expression for $d\eta/dV$ and $\frac{d^2}{dV^2}$. The first derivative conversion is the following:

$\frac{da}{dV}=\frac{da}{d\eta}\cdot \frac{d\eta}{dV}$

Then what are the functions to convert the following second derivatives in terms of $\eta$ to volume $V$?

$$\frac{d^2a}{dV^2}=\frac{d^2a}{d\eta^2}$$
then
$$\frac{d^2a}{dxdV}=\frac{d^2a}{dxd\eta}$$

Comment: Use the product rule.

Comment: What is $x$? And what is its relation to both $\eta$ and $V$? Are the derivatives you wrote partials or totals?

Comment: @user121330 My experience with the product rule is just in differentiating two functions, i.e. (a b)' = a'b + ab'. I don't see how to use that to accomplish my goal.

Comment: @user225318 x can be temperature or composition in my case. My assumption is that η and V are constant wrt x. Also, they're partial differentials, but I don't know how to write that notation on this site. My apologies.

Comment: I'd do it with Liebnitz notation. If you don't see it, there's always the wikipedia page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can apply the chain rule to get higher order derivatives:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}u} 
&=& \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}u}\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} 
\\ \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}u^2} 
&=& \frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}u^2} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} + \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}u}\right)^{\! \!2} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}
\end{eqnarray*}

The main idea to understand is that, as differential operators:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u} = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}u}\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$$

Comment: My thinking is that this is a property of derivatives that I could look up, which I have been trying to do. Do you know of any material that I could read where these ideas are explained in further detail? A proof or something? So that I can work this out and convince myself of its truth.

Comment: Also, if ETA is not a function of x, then do I need to do anything special with the function d2a/dxdETA to convert it to d2a/dxdV? Or can I just use the chain rule as I've used it for the first derivative case that I showed in my original question?

Comment: http://bfy.tw/CBs

Comment: Any ideas for the analogous formula for nth order derivatives?

Comment: @Wakabaloola https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule See higher derivatives

Answer (score 4):

Your question is unclear so I'll give a general answer.

$y$ is a function of $x$. we change the variables such that $x=g(t)$.

this means $dx=g'(t)dt$.

use this representation:

$$y''=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$

now substitute $dx=g'(t)dt$:

$$y''=\frac{1}{g'(t)}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{g'(t)}\frac{dy}{dt}\right)$$

Comment: What information are you looking for that would add clarity?